# Unable to execute main method class in RAD 7.5

Tags: java, ibm-rad

I have class with main method just to print "Hello World" when trying to execute I am getting exception as ClassNotFoundException.

I have another class with main method but invokes a WebService I am getting the "Internal error" as attached image and when clicked on Yes button RAD need to be closed.

Please help me how do I set any classpath or any other parameters. Please as well let me know if any more details I need to provide.

[image]

**UPDATE**
copying eclipse.ini file.

-vm
D:\Program Files\IBM\SDP\jdk\jre\bin\javaw.exe
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.0.101.R34x_v20081125.jar
-install
D:\Program Files\IBM\SDP
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_1.0.101.R34x_v20080731
-vmargs
-Xquickstart
-Xms40m
-Xmx1024m
-Xmnx64m
-Xgcpolicy:gencon
-Xscmx96m
-Xshareclasses:name=IBMSDP_%u
-Xnolinenumbers
-XX:MaxPermSize=128M
-Dcom.ibm.ws.management.event.max_polling_interval=1000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RAD is really a memory hog. You should be running on a PC with at least 2 GB ram, 4 is preferable. Give RAD as much as you can via the eclipse.ini file such as below.

```
-vmargs
-Xms256m
-Xmx2048m
```

I would recommend against using RAD anyway. Unless you're using RUP or WebSphere development and absolutely have to use it, I'd go with plain old Eclipse. RAD is just too bloated... If this doesn't solve your problem post your .log file, and eclipse.ini file.

Comment: Likely in the RAD installation directory.

Comment: I see this issue occurs particularly when I am trying to build a class or project automatically or manually. I tried searching .log file in entire IBM installed directory could not find.

Comment: according to your eclipse.ini, you're only allowing a max of 1GB to RAD. Up that to 2048. Also consider increasing the permGen to 256m

Comment: thank you so much for helping me out here. I values I set to -Xms40m
-Xmx1535m and -XX:MaxPermSize=512M but could not increase to 2G, I am getting error as "Unable to start JVM".